# Interpreting (and getting beyond) cryptic console output

Tags: javascript, dom, d3.js

Asking the right question (yep, the one held too stupid to be uttered) has it's own challenges. Since having started to flirt with d3.js, I seem to have no shortage of these. Here's one which, though for me quite pressing, I've already been warned may be too subjective.

Sometimes a DOM structure conflicts with what is expected: certain elements are perhaps siblings rather than children (perhaps the result of some filter function), or appear to be missing entirely (say an element which for some reason is being ignored).

In these cases, the DOM inspector can, though not necessarily misleading, be a frustration, and we are left to troubleshoot using the console and logs.

Sometimes, however, the console itself seems of little help. I'm thinking of those instances where you're confronted with a series of brackets, perhaps a hint at data, but -frustratingly- a series of error messages when trying to access it.

I see plenty incidental wildfire, but wonder is there a more or less comprehensive guide somewhere to the interpretation of cryptic console output, covering topics such as:

- How the various object types are represented
- What approach serves best to interrogate each
- How to interpret various configurations of empty, square, curly and other brackets
- Strategies for penetrating deeper regions of the DOM tree
- Slights of hand to improve console representation and readability
- Interpretation pitfalls to be aware of

Glad of any good leads..
Thanks

Comment: What's cryptic about your console output? Are you having trouble understanding Javascript error messages? Or do you need help using `console.log()` and related functions?

Comment: Imagine a complex hierarchy of svg:g elements, indexing  impacted by nth-of-type and other filter functions, and leaf node data subject to sometimes nested transformations.

I really didn't want to get sidetracked, but here just one example, an svg:g element within a DOM tree. Filtered selections on a sane and populated (static svg display ok) DOM tree are failing.
 
    `whatever=[object SVGGElement],[object SVGGElement]`
    `whatever.toSource()=[[{__data__:[]}], [{__data__:[]}], [], []]`
 
Current console usage skills leave me unable to grope my way towards leafier parts of the DOM tree..

Comment: Assuming you're using a decent web inspector (e.g. Safari or Chrome), the easiest way to explore a static DOM is by right-clicking on the element (or somewhere close) and selecting "Inspect Element". Rather than messing with the command line, you now have a live DOM tree to interactively explore. Since I'll run into the comment character limit with long urls, I'll continue in an answer.

Comment: Ok, admitted, with thousands of objects on the screen, I've until now avoided Safari and Chrome because they took aeons===hours to load. Firefox has been from the very start been more tolerant and  has only ever taken a second or two to load. I've yet to analyse the bottlenecks, but am now cleaning up code in strict mode in the hope of seeing some quick wins in Chrome and Safari. Following that, I can try out some of these suggestions.

Comment: If your computer takes hours to load Chrome, something is wrong with your computer. If your web page takes hours to load in Chrome, something is wrong with your web page. I've built d3.js visualizations with over a quarter of a million data points and they load in all modern (desktop) browsers in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

one really grat start is to follow these tutorials and introduction on d3.js:
http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3

in particular this section explains arrays and how they work:
[http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/data-types](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3)

I think this should be really helpful if you're just starting with d3

Answer (score 0):

Something that may help for some of the cases you've mentioned for D3 specifically is the DOM inspector that [vida.io](https://vida.io) ([tutorial here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WuJXuPRbLI)) provides. In general, there's no answer to your questions however -- all depends on the particular library you're using, browser, versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to command line usage (e.g. `console.log()`) maybe the interactive web inspector would be more helpful to you. Details for [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). Although I find it less useful, there's also [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) if you prefer Firefox.